# Google Colab上で計算結果をhtmlに変換したい

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Google Colab上で新規の計算結果をhtmlに変換する方法を知りたいです。

まず現在行っていることを記入します。
run.ipynbとtest1.ipynbの2つを持っています。

run.ipynb

```
%run test1.ipynb
!jupyter nbconvert --to html test1.ipynb
```

(test1.ipynbを一回計算させて、test1.ipynbをhtmlに変換する)

test1.ipynb

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = list(range(10))
y = list(range(10))
plt.plot(x, y)
```

（単純に直線の図を描くだけ）

行いたいことは、 `%run test1.ipynb` で図を作成したものを `jupyter nbconvert --to html test1.ipynb` でhtmlに描きたいだけですが、何をしても真っ白（test1.ipynbが動いていない）の結果しか表示されません。

質問ですが、`%run test1.ipynb` で作成された新規の図を含めた状態でhtmlで保存したいのですが、どのようにしたらよいかご教授をお願いします。

Comment: `--execute`のオプションの追加を試してみては？ 承認マークは付いていませんが多数のプラス投票がされています。[How export a Jupyter notebook to HTML from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901154/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。[--execute]オプションを加えることで無事に出来上がりました。メモ用command line: jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html test1.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

@Kunif様に解決案を伺い、試したところ、上手く行きましたのでメモ用に記しておきます

オリジナル コード:

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to html test1.ipynb
```

下記のコマンドにするとプログラム(test1.ipynb)を動かし、そこで作成された新規の図を含めてhtmlに保存してくれます

```
!jupyter nbconvert --execute　--to html test1.ipynb
```

蛇足かもしれませんが、test1.ipynbに引数を渡したい場合は

```
!NB_ARGS=args jupyter nbconvert --execute　--to html test1.ipynb
```

この場合、test1.ipynbの中に

```
input = os.environ['NB_ARGS']
```

を記入しておきますと、正しく引数が渡されます。

ありがとうございました